# Firebase Facebook authentication not returning email for some users

Tags: javascript, firebase

I run an Ionic 3 app with Firebase. Everything was fine until one of the users logged in and his email address was blank in the Firebase Authentication section. Does the code below need any additional permissions set for it to retreive the email address?

```
  facebookLogin(): void {
    this.facebook.login(['email']).then((response) => {
      const facebookCredential = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider
        .credential(response.authResponse.accessToken);

      firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(facebookCredential)
        .then((success) => {
          // console.log("Firebase success: " + JSON.stringify(success));
          this.user = success;
          this.doLoginStuff(success, 'facebook');
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          if (error.code === "auth/account-exists-with-different-credential") {
            this.presentToast(error.message)
          }
          // alert("Firebase failure: " + JSON.stringify(error));
        });

    }).catch((error) => { console.log(error) });
  }
```

Comment: I believe it's possible for users to opt-out of allowing your application to receive their email during the Facebook sign-in confirmation dialog. That may be the underlying issue.

Comment: The app is suppose to give users access based on their email address. Do you know of any other unique identifiers that can be used instead? So someone adds users to an "alowedUsers" list and when logging in, if the email is there, the user gets access.

Comment: Not ever user necessarily _has_ an email address set on Facebook - for example if they registered using their mobile. If they have one set, it must be confirmed; and in some rare cases even then some privacy setting can apparently make you not get it even if the user granted the permission. Don't rely on an e-mail address in combination with Facebook login. _"Do you know of any other unique identifiers that can be used instead?"_ - none that you could get upfront to add to your list.

Comment: Yeah ... I was reading this just now "Note, even if you request the email permission it is not guaranteed you will get an email address. For example, if someone signed up for Facebook with a phone number instead of an email address, the email field may be empty."  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/#reference-email

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `.signInWithCredential`, use `.onAuthStateChanged` Or, this may be a Facebook-side issue. Browse to developers.facebook.com and check that your app is switched on/public and then check your app review page to make sure you can get emails.

[image]

Comment: _"and then check your app review page to make sure you can get emails."_ - this permission is approved for all apps by default, as it also says there - nothing to check in that regard.

Comment: These are set just like you have them in the screenshot. Thank you

Comment: I already have these set. I only need email address. Funny thing is the field `user.email` is still empty but `additionalUserInfo.profile.email` shows the correct email address.

Comment: I too can only see the email in `additionalUserInfo.profile.email` and when I then re-authenticate on the server side using `FireBaseAuth.VerifyIdToken` to get a decoded token, it doesn't return these additional information